# QCustomPlot adding double to graph take to much time

Tags: eigen, qcustomplot

I have this code:

```
QCustomPlot* plot;

QCPGraph* graph = plot->addGraph();

for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {

    double x_l = static_cast<double>(buffer[i * 3]);
    double y_l = static_cast<double>(buffer[i * 3 + 1);
    double z_l = static_cast<double>(buffer[i * 3 + 2]);

    r = A * v + v1; // r and v1 and v are Eigen::Vector3d, A is Eigen::Matrix3d 

    graph->addData(x_l, x_l);
}
```

This for loop take 240 millisec!!!!

If I replacing the last line with:

```
graph->addData(5.1121, 6.7457) //random number which are also double
```

The for loop takes 4 millisec!!!

Why is the difference so huge???

The original line suppose to be:

```
graph->addData(r[0], r[1]);
```

But it's also take around 300 millisec.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Did you compile with optimizations?

Comment: regular compiling

Comment: Compile with optimization then. Eigen is very slow without compiler-optimization enabled.